# Qt how to receive Python send string

Tags: python, c++, qt

I have python to send simple string on local network code is following :

```
import socket
import os

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
stringTosend = ("Hello,World")
print(stringTosend)
sock.connect(('192.168.2.39', 42207))
try:
 sock.sendall(stringTosend)
except socket.error:
 print 'Send failed'
 sys.exit()
print'Sent'
```

And in my QT I set up  label that show the "Helloworld" 
What can i  do in the qt?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Qt, you should follow the event driven architecture. Qt's event loop should be always ready to [receive new events](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#What_requires_a_running_event_loop.3F). Generally, You can connect a slot to any `QObject`'s signal to get notified that a specific event has happened, and your slot should contain the code that runs when that signal fires.

Starting from Qt5, you can also connect to [C++11 lambdas](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) (instead of slots). I have leveraged that in order to make the code as minimal as possible. Please note that in a real project, You might need to separate that into different classes, each with its own responsibility, to keep things more maintainable. . .

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //the label to show received string
    QLabel label("no connection yet");
    //tcp server object to listen for incoming connections
    QTcpServer tcpServer;
    //connect the server's newConnection signal to get notified for new connections
    QObject::connect(&tcpServer, &QTcpServer::newConnection, [&tcpServer, &label] {
        //get a new tcp socket for the incoming connection
        QTcpSocket* socket = tcpServer.nextPendingConnection();
        //change the label to reflect the new state
        label.setText("received connection");
        //connect the socket's readyRead signal to get notified
        //when data is available on the socket
        QObject::connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, [socket, &label] {
            //receive available data from the socket
            QByteArray received = socket->readAll();
            //change label's text (assuming text is encoded using UTF-8)
            label.setText(QString::fromUtf8(received));
            //close and delete the socket when done
            socket->close();
            socket->deleteLater();
        });
    });
    //start listening on port 42207
    if(!tcpServer.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 42207))
        label.setText("server listen error");
    //show the label
    label.show();
    //start event loop
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks your detail reply, cause i am fresher to this. this code where i should put? create new file in Souces??

Comment: This should be your `main.cpp` file. Don't forget to add dependency on the Qt network module in your project's `.pro` file (i.e. `QT += network`)

Comment: Mike do you mind i asking another question how can i put the code in my mainwindow cpp because i  leave a label in the screen that is use for show python sending string

Comment: The simplest way would be: have the server object as a member of your mainwindow class, start listening and connect signals in your mainwindow's constructor. Optionally, you might want to use slots instead of lambda functions. . .

Comment: Thanks your reply, I still have some confuse is how i can build a server in mainwindow class

Comment: you just need to add `QTcpServer tcpServer;` to your `mainwindow.h` file in the private section (a member in the `MainWindow` class), then start listening and connect to signals in `MainWindow`'s constructor.

Comment: @robinshion , Glad it worked for you. Please add this as another answer to the question instead of editing my answer :)

Comment: I think that you are better using slots instead of lambdas in your case, the code will be more readable, just try it before posting the other answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply I added #include<QTcpServer> in the mainwindow.h, so what should i modify the mainwindow cpp??

Comment: yes, you should start listening, and connect signals in the constructor mplementation, as mentioned in my previous comment. . .

Comment: is that means qt will be server and client ??

Comment: no worries :) . No, no, Qt here is the server, python is where you are connecting (the client). Adapting the code above to your `MainWindow` class has nothing to do with roles

Comment: thanks your reply  can i occupy your some time for check my answer?? thanks

Comment: Hi mike I put the QTcpServer tcpServer in my mmainwindow.h and i put the code :   tcpServer.listen(QHostAddress::Any,42207);   readMessage(); in my mainwindow's constructor  now it can keep listening but I don not know how to show the string on the label, could you help me ???